# Email template customization in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, email-templates, order-email

I would like to customise template of new order email. I found below codes in template

```
<p>
    {{trans "Thank you for your order from %store_name." store_name=$store.getFrontendName()}}
    {{trans "We are committed to provide enhance your online shopping experience. Once your package ships we will send you a tracking number."}} 
    {{trans 'You can check the status of your order by <a href="%account_url">logging into your account</a>.' account_url=$this.getUrl($store,'customer/account/',[_nosid:1]) |raw}}
</p>
```

I would like make **bold** `%store_name`. How can I do that ?

I would like to customize footer
`{{template config_path="design/email/footer_template"}}` also. Where is the location of the footer ?

Comment: What is your Magento version?

Comment: Thanks @Piyush for your reply. I am using Magento2 . Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Email templates footer file is located at below path

> your_Magento2_root/vendor/magento/module-email/view/frontend/email/footer.html

**Note:** changes in this file will reflect in all email templates.